# How to add diferent attributes to each node of an xmlfile using xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, bash, shell, edit, xmlstarlet

I was trying to edit an xml file using xmlstarlet in a bash script.
But I found I have a problem when trying to give different values to the same attributes in the same nodes, let me show you with this example:
Using this code

```sh
xmlstarlet ed -L -s /foo -t elem -n bar -v "" -i //bar -t attr -n id -v bar1 $file  
xmlstarlet ed -L -s /foo -t elem -n bar -v "" -i //bar -t attr -n id -v bar2 $file
```

using this i get the following result in $file:

```html
<foo>
  <bar id="bar1" id="bar2"/>
  <bar id="bar2"/>
</foo>
```

But what I am trying to achieve looks like this:

```html
<foo>
  <bar id="bar1"/>
  <bar id="bar2"/>
</foo>
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Add content of $file to your question.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer Cyrus, right now I am trying to apply it to my project, secondarily the content of $file is just a line that in this situation would be <foo/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this file:

```
<foo>
</foo>
```

Command:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
   --subnode "//foo" --type elem -n "bar" \
   --insert "//bar[1]" --type attr -n "id" --value "bar1" \
   --subnode "//foo" --type elem -n "bar" \
   --insert "//bar[2]" --type attr -n "id" --value "bar2" file.xml
```

If you don't want to count new elements use `last()`:

```
xmlstarlet edit --omit-decl \
   --subnode "//foo" --type elem -n "bar" \
   --insert "//bar[last()]" --type attr -n "id" --value "bar1" \
   --subnode "//foo" --type elem -n "bar" \
   --insert "//bar[last()]" --type attr -n "id" --value "bar2" file.xml
```

Output in both cases:

```
<foo>
  <bar id="bar1"/>
  <bar id="bar2"/>
</foo>
```