# awk not creating table . Only the tags are getting printed

Tags: shell, awk

Here awk is used with shell script. I am trying to print the fields in e.txt in a table format. This is the code used.  But i am not getting a table as my output. The output is included below. How to get this code to print the table. should something else be included.

e.txt

```
5 a 678
4 b 7899
```

Shell script using awk

```
 awk 'BEGIN {print "<table>"}
               {print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"}
         END   {print "</table>"}' /home/scripts/e.txt
```

Output:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td>5</td><td>a</td></tr>
 <tr><td>4</td><td>b</td></tr>
 </table>
```

I need to print it in the form of a table with some styles .

Comment: What output are you wanting to get if not that?

Comment: @SaAk, I believe you forgot to put `<html>` tags in your `awk` code? If yes then you could try my code mentioned.

Comment: I suggest to use xmlstarlet. See: [How to add diferent attributes to each node of an xmlfile using xmlstarlet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48061266/3776858)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following code and let us know.

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "<html>" ORS "<table>"} {print "<tr><td>" $1 "</td><td>" $2 "</td></tr>"} END{print "</table>" ORS "</html>"}' Input_file > test.html
```